# Why doesn't System.Net.Http.HttpClientFactory implement System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory?

Tags: dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.7.2, ihttpclientfactory

I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2 and am trying to use `IHttpClientFactory` to create `HttpClient` instances.

I downloaded the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` v7 NuGet Package and now have access to `System.Net.Http.HttpClientFactory`.

Am I meant to use `HttpClientFactory.Create()` to create `HttpClient`s?

Or do I have to use DI and `IHttpClientFactory`?

What is `HttpClientFactory` used for and why doesn't it implement `IHttpClientFactory`?

Comment: Have you had a chance to review [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory)

Comment: @Nkosi I have. That article is for .NET Core and above. I'm using .NET Framework.

Comment: You should use the DefaultHttpClientFactory concrete class which implements the IHttpClientFactory interface.

Comment: @PeterCsala that's only available in .NET Core 2.1+. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the [source code of the `DefaultHttpClientFactory`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e55c908229e36f99a52745d4ee85316a0e8bb6a2/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs) and even though it is part of the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` namespace it is marked as `internal`.

Gladly the [`AddHttpClient` extension method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/215b39abf947da7a40b0cb137eab4bceb24ad3e3/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L23) can do the DI registration of the above class on our behalf.

```cs
services.TryAddSingleton<DefaultHttpClientFactory>();
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpClientFactory>(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DefaultHttpClientFactory>());
```

So, all you need to do is:

1. create a `ServiceCollection`
2. call the `AddHttpClient`
3. build it to have a `ServiceProvider`
4. call the `GetRequiredService`

In order to do that in .NET Framework 4.7.2 you need to use the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package.

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

class Program
{
    private static readonly ServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    static Program()
    {
        serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddHttpClient().BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
        Console.WriteLine(factory == null); //False
    }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73642025/unable-to-make-httpclientfactory-working-from-a-net-framework-4-7-2-winform-pro/73855685#73855685) I have detailed how to do the same with `SimpleInjector`